# KonvaJS swaping node's position in a group is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, konvajs

I am working on a drag and drop project using Konva js and i want to be able to swap the position of 2 nodes when a node is drag onto another node.
In my code the swapping of the position works fine as i can click each node to console.log to see the position of the node has been swapped. But the position of the nodes after being updated is currently in the middle point of two nodes.

[dragging node 65 to node 35 results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPIgq.png)

```
 nodeGroup.on("dragstart", function (evt) {
    if (evt.evt.ctrlKey) {
      stage.stopDrag();
      stage.startDrag();
      return;
    }
    //nodeGroup.moveToTop();
    const draggedNode = evt.target; // The node being drag
    draggedNode.zIndex(50); // set the drag node on top

    var targetRect = node.getClientRect();
    var nodeGroup = evt.currentTarget;
    oldColor = nodeGroup.children[0].attrs.fill;
    if (nodeGroup) {
      if (nodeGroup.children[0].attrs.fill === "red") return;
      nodeGroup.children[0].attrs.fill = "red";
    }
    //save the node's original position
    draggedNodeStartPosition = { x: nodeGroup.x(), y: nodeGroup.y() };
  });
```

```
  nodeGroup.on("dragend", function (evt) {
    if (!evt.evt) return;
    if (evt.evt.ctrlKey) {
      return;
    }

    var draggedNode = evt.currentTarget; // The node being drag
    var draggedRect = draggedNode.getClientRect(); // Dragged node 's bounding box
    var hasCollision = false;

    //check all of the nodes to find the node that is overlapping
    for (var n = 0; n < numberOfData; n++) {
      if (`node-${n}` !== draggedNode.id()) {
        // skip checking the node being drag
        const checkNode = stage.find(`#node-${n}`)[0]; // the node being colided or drag into
        const checkRect = checkNode.getClientRect();
        if (hasOverlap(draggedRect, checkRect)) {
          // Swap the positions of the dragged node and the collided node
          const draggedNodeOldPosition = draggedNodeStartPosition;
          const checkNodePosition = { x: checkNode.x(), y: checkNode.y() };

          draggedNode.position(checkNodePosition);
          //checkNode.position(draggedNodeOldPosition);

          // Optional: Update zindex properties if needed
          const draggedNodeZIndex = draggedNode.zIndex();
          draggedNode.zIndex(checkNode.zIndex());
          checkNode.zIndex(draggedNodeZIndex);

          hasCollision = true;
          break; // Exit the loop since we found a collision
        }
      }
    }
    draggedNode.getLayer().draw(); //reset layer

    // If there was no collision, update the old position
    if (!hasCollision) {
      draggedNode.position(draggedNodeStartPosition);
    }

    const targetRect = evt.target.getClientRect();
    nodeGroup.children[0].attrs.fill = oldColor;
    var target = stage.getIntersection(stage.getPointerPosition());
  });
```

I tried a number of methods including changing the position of only the node being drag, and it still moves the node to the middle point instead at the position of the node that is drag onto

[codepen](https://codepen.io/an-khuat-quang/pen/abXQPbm?editors=1111)

Comment: Are those nodes that you are switching groups?

Comment: Yes, i am trying to switch positions of nodes that are in a group

Comment: This question is quite involved and not a good fit for SO. Please join the Konva Discord and I will help you there. I will be asking you to make a cut-down demo in codepen or a similar online sandbox - something that shows, in minimal code, the gist of what you are trying to do. Do that and ask again on discord.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your code if you are using Konva.Groups or other shapes. However, since I see mention of 'nodeGroup' then it is possible you are using groups.

The position of groups is not as straightforward as it is with other shapes. Groups *do* have position, but often we don't set it explicitly, so it stays initially at (0,0). But when you drag a group, either directly or via a transform, the group.position() *is* changed.

With other shapes, as per your requirement. we can use the position to switch the shapes location  - we would have to do some math when moving say a circle and a rect because their *position* location differs.  But it is logical.

But with the Group you would need to be mindful of how the group.position relates to the child shape postions.

Comment: Thanks for the info, the thing that i am trying to switch position is a group of a rectangle and a text node on a layer . then i have a big group that contains all the child element so that i can do operations like zoom in and out.